# How to convert selected anchor points to smooth in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, anchor-point

Is there a shortcut key for converting selected anchor points to smooth? If not, is there a way to set one?

I've looked in the keyboard shortcuts menu, but I can not see an option. Do i have to always click on the button to convert?

[image]

Comment: `alt + drag` with the **Pen Tool** selected or the **Convert Anchor Point Tool** (`shift + c`)

Comment: Although if there was a way to do it just by keyboard. Like select the point press button and done!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell there is no way to set a keyboard shortcut to do this.

You can do this with the **Pen Tool** (<kbd>P</kbd>) by selecting the point and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>drag</kbd>

or the **Convert Anchor Point Tool** (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>) by selecting the point and <kbd>drag</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can shift-select multiple points using direct selection tool, and then click convert anchor points button just once.